# Ionic Error: Can't bind Angular structural directive to since it isn't a known property of

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm developing a tab based application with Ionic Framework (version 5). The following error occurs only when I modify the code and the application is automatically reloaded on a page other than the "home page".

[image]

I have already tried to import the modules `CommonModule`, `FormsModule` and `IonicModule` into the module class of each page but doesn't work, the workaround that makes directives like `ngFor` work is to reload the application on the home page.

---

Specifically this error occurs in the pages `new-article`:

`src/app/pages/new-article/new-article.page.html`

```html
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let url of artcile.photos"><img [src]="url"/></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

`src/app/pages/new-article/new-article.module.ts`

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    NewArticlePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [NewArticlePage]
})
export class NewArticlePageModule {}
```

As I said before, it's a tab based application, all pages are handled through the routing module:
`src/app/tabs/tabs-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
      },
      ...
      {
        path: 'new-article',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/new-article/new-article-routing.module').then(m => m.NewArticlePageRoutingModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

If anyone has any suggestions on this I would be grateful.

---

**UPDATES**

This error can occur when you import `component-routing.module` instead of `component.module` into `tabs-routing.module.ts`.

Comment: show your component html, and module where it's declared

Comment: Ion-col is missing, pls import its module as well. Ngfor is not missing.

Comment: Are you sure you want to import the routing module instead of the newarticlepagemodule?

Comment: @tano I hadn't noticed that, now it works! I probably wasn't careful using the autocomplete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to load module of components in the routes, not a routing module:

```
  {
    path: 'new-article',
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/new-article/new-article.module').then(m => m.NewArticlePageModule)
  },
```

That's the correct way to use routing in the Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're importing the new article page's routing module in your tabs routing module, where you should actually be importing the new article page's base module. Within `tabs-routing.module.ts`, change this:

```
{
        path: 'new-article',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/new-article/new-article-routing.module').then(m => m.NewArticlePageRoutingModule)
},
```

to this:

```
{
        path: 'new-article',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/new-article/new-article-page.module').then(m => m.NewArticlePageModule)
},
```

I hope that fixes it for you.